# Example of CurveZMQ in C# and Why can't I use SetOption() to CURVE_SECRETKEY when using CurveZMQ?

Tags: c#, .net, zeromq

I want to use CurveZMQ to for secure authentication and confidentiality for communications between a client and a server. But I cannot find any example in C#. I try to follow the API document step by step. And I encounter the problem in Setting CURVE_PUBLICKEY, CURVE_SECRETKEY and CURVE_SERVERKEY.

Here is my code. 
The socket 'server.CurveSecretKey' threw an exception of type 'ZeroMQ.ZException': 
at ZeroMQ.ZSocket.GetOption(ZSocketOption option, IntPtr optionValue, Int32& optionLength)\r\n at ZeroMQ.ZSocket.GetOption(ZSocketOption option, Byte[]& value)\r\n at ZeroMQ.ZSocket.get_CurveSecretKey()"

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();
    }

var context = new ZContext();
server = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.ROUTER);
server.SetOption(ZSocketOption.CURVE_SERVER, 1);
string curveSKey = "8E0BDD697628B91D8F245587EE95C5B04D48963F79259877B49CD9063AEAD3B7";
var skey = StringToByteArray(curveSKey);
server.SetOption(ZSocketOption.CURVE_SECRETKEY, skey);
```

Can you give me some example in C# about CurveZMQ?

Comment: Ya well... I have a problem, the current binary `libzmq.dll\/.so` didn't "get" the CurveZMQ features... You need to re-compile the `zeromq4-x` or `libzmq` projects from source.

Comment: About the `byte[]`: Actually, if you set any `byte[]` using ZSocket.SetOption, you should escape NUL characters, they are used as terminators in C programs. So basically said, if you do SetOption, don't do it using NUL. If you do set Identity, do this without NUL, or do this using rng.GetNonZeroBytes.

Comment: Felix Fu, we're you able to get your code working?  I am looking for some C# examples using CurveZMQ but have also noticed the lack of example code.  I was wondering if you had any examples you could share.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the as a string, not as byte-array.

```
var skey = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(StringToByteArray(curveSKey));
server.SetOption(ZSocketOption.CURVE_SECRETKEY, skey);
```